# XAMPP [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp, shutdown

I am using XAMPP to test some websites. I have created a Wordpress website with database. It works perfectly until I shut down XAMPP. When I try to start XAMPP again I get the error message next to the MySQL

```
[mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly
```

I have found the following solution that works - when I delete `ibdata1` or `ib_logfile0` and run XAMPP again MySql works but I don't have access to the database I was working on so this solution is not good enough. I have tried to reinstall XAMPP and install it in C:\ directory but it didn't change anything.